# How to change indirect addressing in MIPS?

Tags: mips, memory-address

I am trying to convert the indirect addressing to native MIPS instructions

I already understood how to do it but this is a single choice objective question and two options seems exact same to me

Q) lw $t0, @($t1) # $t0 <- M[M[$t1]]

(A)
lw $t1, 0($t1)
lw $t0, 0($t1)

(B)
lw $t0, 0($t1)
lw $t0, 0($t0)

Both of them seem same to give same result in the end or am I missing something

Comment: They do not give the same result: They put different values into `$t1`.

Comment: Yes, they put different values in $t1 but $t0 is same, right? I am only concerned with the end state of $t0.

Comment: The person asking the question appears to be concerned about t1 also. The two options are not exactly the same: they have different effects on t1.

Comment: That makes sense. Didn't think of that. Thanks for the help.